# Incrementing enums in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have `enum stage [:one, :two, :three, :four]` in a model.

When the controller action `next_stage` is called (button clicked by the user to send it to the next stage), I want to go incrementally from stage X to Y. What's the easiest way to do this? I currently use a big, gross case statement, but I feel like I can do it better. I'll provide my use-case:

```
Class MyController
  def next_stage
    # @my_controller.stage => "two"
    @my_controller.stage.value++ unless @my_controller.stage.four?
    # @my_controller.stage => "three"
  end
end
```

Comment: I misunderstood what you were looking for. I changed my answer to suit.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, if you're trying to store state that moves in a certain order, you should use a state machine.  https://github.com/aasm/aasm supports using enums to store the state. You could do something like this;

```
aasm :column => :stage, :enum => true do
  state :stage1, :initial => true
  state :stage2
  state :stage3
  state :stage4

  event :increment_stage do
    transitions from: :stage1, to: :stage2
    transitions from: :stage2, to: :stage3
    transitions from: :stage3, to: :stage4
  end
end
```

it not only cleans up your logic, but the tests will be simpler, and you can do all sorts of callbacks on different events.  It's really good for any sort of workflow as well (say moving a post from review to approved etc.)

EDIT: Can I also suggest that if you don't want to use a state machine then you at least move this state shifting logic into your model? Controllers are about access control, models are about state.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of hackish but the only way to get an integer out of an enum that I have found is doing 
`model.read_attribute('foo')`
So you could try to do

```
def next_stage
  @my_controller.update_column(:stage, @my_controller.read_attribute('stage')+1) unless @my_controller.four?
end
```

Comment: The value of an enum is accessible through a hash syntax using the plural of the enum. `MyModel.stages[:one]` returns `0`.  And it is a hash with indifferent access so `MyModel.stages['one']` also works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit strange, what is `@my_controller`? What is `stage`?

Besides that, if I understand correctly, what you want is this:

```
@my_controller[:stage] += 1 unless @my_controller.four?
```

Enumerations are stored as integers in the database, and they start at 0, with increments of 1. So, simply access the raw attribute data and increment it.

Comment: I updated my question, but `stage` is stored in the model, and upon clicking a button, that controller action `next_stage` is called.

Comment: Ok, so my code will work. It's basically the same as the one Jared answered above, but shorter and not updating the database.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a gem [simple_enum](https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum) which lets you use more powerful enums.

The enum will let you use both integers and/or symbols, then you can do something like

```
@my_controller.stage.value_cd += 1 unless @my_controller.stage.last_stage?
```

You can use it with ActiveRecord/Mongoid, but also any other object.

For an ORM like Mongoid, your model could look like this

```
class Project
  as_enum :status, {
        idea: 0, 
        need_estimate: 1,
        in_progress: 2,
        finished: 3,
        paid: 4,
        field: { type: Integer, default: 0 }

  def next_step!
    self.status_cd += 1 unless self.paid?
  end
end

project = Project.new
project.status # => :idea
project.need_estimate? #=> false
project.next_step!
project.need_estimate? #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I get this right. Maybe you can try  this:

```
    Class MyController
      def next_stage
        @my_controller.stage.increment! :value rescue nil
      end
    end
```

Answer (score -1):

**NEW ANSWER**

Ok, I think I better understand what you are looking for. How about this:

In your model set up your Enum with a hash rather than an array:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum stage: {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4} #just makes more sense when talking about stages
end
```

Then you can use the current status' index:

```
Class MyController
  def next_stage
    # @my_controller.stage => "two"
    current_stage = MyClass.stages[@my_controller.stage] # returns => 1
    current_stage += 1 unless current_stage == 4   # returns => 2
    @my_controller.update! stage: current_stage 
    # @my_controller.stage => "three"
  end
end
```

If I understand the docs correctly, this may also work:

```
Class MyController
  def next_stage
    # @my_controller.stage => "two"
    @my_controller.update! stage: MyClass.stages[@my_controller.stage] + 1 unless @my_controller.stage == :four 
    # @my_controller.stage => "three"
  end
end
```

this is off the cuff and could probably be cleaned up in some ways. I can't experiment very much because I don't have something setup in a rails app with an enum to mess around with.

old answer left for archival purposes.

```
def next_stage
  self.next
end
```

**edit** I saw enums and thought you were shortening enumerable to enum (as in `x.to_enum`). Not so sure this won't work for you in some form. You asked for something other than an ugly case statement. You could use an enumerator that takes the current enum from that column to set the starting point, and the end point is 4 (or :four depending on how you write it) and have the rescue at the end of the enumerator return your max value.

Comment: I ran the following in console and got the corresponding, very odd, results:

`Object.last.stage => "review"`

`Object.last.stage.next => "reviex"`

Notice, it went from 'w' to 'x' so `next` seems like a String method.

Comment: Not sure what you are even talking about here. Please show some more code in your question. The above will work for any enumerator. I have no clue what your question means.

Comment: I add this caveat to my comment above: You need to add the above code to the Enumerable module.

Comment: Enumerable != Enum  http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: @Beartech I'm using an Enum, not Enumerable. A Ruby Enum returns the string value, so calling `next` refers to String#next.

Comment: Reading further, the hash syntax is not really needed, `enum stage [:one, :two, :three, :four]` will work just fine. But if you use the hash syntax you could set it to: `enum stage: {one: 1, two: 4, three: 3, four: 4}` and it would look more logical if you happen to look at the raw data in the database. In fact I'll edit my answer to match this.